# Understanding Multiple Column Usage with "Group By"

Tags: sql, group-by

I understood grouping a table by a column's data however I'm having trouble to understand to group a table by multiple columns.

Can anyone give me an example to understand multiple column usage with Group By?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there are numerous examples out there, but here is a use case:

A transaction journal table in banking has fields like:

```
Account_Number,
Posting_Date,
Transaction_Type,
Transaction_Amount
```

Every account can have multiple transactions on any given day, I'd like to analyze trends in Transaction Type over time (ie: debit card purchases vs checks vs atm withdrawals, etc), so I use:

```
SELECT Posting_Date
     , Transaction_Type
     , COUNT(*) 'Number of Transactions'
     , AVG(Transaction_Amount) 'Average Transaction Amount' 
FROM Transaction_Journal
GROUP BY Posting_Date
       , Transaction_Type
ORDER BY Posting_Date
       , Transaction_Type
```

In reality I'd probably `PIVOT` the results so I could easily see the trends, but the idea is shown in my example, multiple columns in `GROUP BY` gets me aggregate information per `Posting_Date` per `Transaction_Type`.